# import in react-scripts react-app-env.d.ts breaks tsc build

Tags: typescript

I want to import types in a file that is generated by react-scripts.

I have created [this minimal repo](https://github.com/dagda1/fooky-types) that shows the problem.

I have this so far:

```
// import * as React from 'react';
// import { MemoryHistory } from 'history';
// import { RenderResult } from 'react-testing-library';

interface Window {
  env: any;
}

type ContextDefaultValue = [string, (val: string) => void];

/* global function for rendering with Router */
declare function renderWithRouter(ui: any, { route, history, }?: {
  route?: string;
  history?: any;
}): any;
```

If I uncomment any of the import statements and run tsc, then renderWithRouter is no longer in the global namespace and I get this error:

> Cannot find name 'renderWithRouter'.

Can I not import types in .d.ts files?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal github project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai I've created this repo which illustrates the problem https://github.com/dagda1/fooky-types

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce your problem. Here are the steps I took: (1) Download repo and open with VS Code. (2) Run `npm install`. (3) Run `npm run build`. No error occur, successfully generate "build" folder.

Comment: Running tsc build also does not result in any error, only nothing is generated.

Comment: from the repo in the link i sent?

Comment: are you running tsc in the repos .bin folder?

Comment: Yes, from your repo. I don't see any .bin folder in your repo (other than ./node_modules/.bin, after running `npm install`); I ran all commands in the top folder.

Comment: @dagda1 are you planning to award the bounty ? Just asking .. um .. for a friend 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir i’m at an airport and can’t see how to award bounty in mobile app.  i hope it is possible

Comment: @dagda1 Not sure how to do it from the mobile app. There is a 24h grace period after the bounty expires so you can still do it tomorrow. 10x 

Comment: did i just award the bounty?

Comment: @dagda1 Yup 10x

Comment: phew.  glad you got it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding an import to a file makes it a module. So in a module if you declare an interface `Window` it is declared local to that module.

If you want to use imports, but still keep the declarations global, you have two options:

**Use `declare global`**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { History } from 'history';
import { RenderResult } from 'react-testing-library';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    env: any;
  }

  declare function renderWithRouter(ui: any, { route, history, }?: {
    route?: string;
    history?: History;
  }): RenderResult;
}
```

**Use `import` types**

```
interface Window {
  env: any;
}

declare function renderWithRouter(ui: any, { route, history, }?: {
  route?: string;
  history?: import('history').History;
}): import('react-testing-library').RenderResult;
```

Either version will work, the `declare global` is easier if you use a lot of types from other modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the official documentation of typescript, the working logic (including this error) and its structure are explained very clearly. [1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html), [2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

***Importing from Modules***

You might start out getting a bunch of errors like `Cannot find name 'require'.`, and `Cannot find name 'define'`.. In these cases, it’s likely that you’re using modules. While you can just convince TypeScript that these exist by writing out

*// For Node/CommonJS*

```
declare function require(path: string): any;
```

or

*// For RequireJS/AMD*

```
declare function define(...args: any[]): any;
```

it’s better to get rid of those calls and use TypeScript syntax for imports.

First, you’ll need to enable some module system by setting TypeScript’s module flag. Valid options are `commonjs`, `amd`, `system`, and `umd`.

*If you had the following Node/CommonJS code:*

```
var foo = require("foo");

foo.doStuff();
```

or the following RequireJS/AMD code:

```
define(["foo"], function(foo) {
    foo.doStuff();
})
```

then you would write the following TypeScript code:

```
import foo = require("foo");

foo.doStuff();
```